# What is the meaning of this sentence? "The right side of $a\equiv b \pmod c$ is less than or equal to the left side."

Tags: modular-arithmetic, terminology

Let us consider a congruence of the form

$$a\equiv b \pmod c$$

What is the meaning of the following sentence?
$$\text{The right side of the congruence is less than or equal to the left side.}$$

---

For context, the Jones, et.al, *American Mathematical Monthly* article ["Diophantine Representation of the Set of Prime Numbers" (PDF link via umd.edu)](http://www.math.umd.edu/%7Elaskow/Pubs/713/Diorepofprimes.pdf) has the following (Lemma 2.4, pg 452; **emphasis** added):

> For any numbers $p$, $n$ and $a\geq 1$ we have the congruence
> $$\chi_a(n) \equiv p^n+\psi_a(n)(a-p) \pmod{2ap-p^2-1}$$
> Furthermore, when $0< p^n<a$, **the right side of the congruence is less than or equal to the left side**.

Comment: I understand it as $a\ge b$

Comment: @user310148: Me too, but I have some doubts.

Comment: What is the context for this ?

Comment: @user310148: I have some diophantine equations and I come across this idea.

Comment: Maybe try posting the whole problem then. We can't do more but guess with what you've given us

Comment: @Blue: It is in this link: http://www.math.umd.edu/~laskow/Pubs/713/Diorepofprimes.pdf Lemma 2.4 page 452.

Comment: Likely it means $\,b < a.\ $ What else could it possibly mean?

Comment: @BillDubuque: You mean $b\le a$.

Comment: @TonyK Yes of course.

Answer (score -1):

I am not an expert on the topic, but I think you can use the definition of congruence modulo which is that $\displaystyle a\equiv b\ (\bmod c) \ \Leftrightarrow a-b=ck$, so I would think you can replace the equality sign with a greater than or equal to. It would then be $\displaystyle a-b\geqslant ck$. I am not sure, however.